# How to refresh table contents in div using jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xhtml

I need your help in order to refresh a div `id="mytable"` in my html once the function is called from a method. Currently, I am loading the full page once it is called using the below lines.

In my java method, I am using the below line to call a javascript method:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("autoRefresh()");
```

The html code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autoRefresh() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>

<div id='mytable'>
    <h1 id='My Table'>
        <table></table>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to create an endpoint on the server which returns the HTML required to populate the `div` element when you make an AJAX request to it. As it stands your question is far too broad.

Comment: I didn't get your answer properly could you please explain

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can load HTML page partial, in your case is everything inside div#mytable.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $( "#mytable" ).load( "your-current-page.html #mytable" );
}, 2000); //refresh every 2 seconds
```

more information read this http://api.jquery.com/load/

#### Update Code (if you don't want it auto-refresh)

```
<button id="refresh-btn">Refresh Table</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   function RefreshTable() {
       $( "#mytable" ).load( "your-current-page.html #mytable" );
   }

   $("#refresh-btn").on("click", RefreshTable);

   // OR CAN THIS WAY
   //
   // $("#refresh-btn").on("click", function() {
   //    $( "#mytable" ).load( "your-current-page.html #mytable" );
   // });


});
</script>
```

Comment: Should I put the above in my autorefresh() function?

Comment: don't, i'm forgot to add setTimeout() there. i've update my code above. it refresh every 2 seconds

Comment: Let me try it and come back ..... Do I need to import or include any jquery library?

Comment: Can you please help in setting a function name, so I can call it. In addition, I don't want it to be refreshed automatically, I want it to be refresh once the function is called and thanks

Comment: @AryWibowo i used your autoupdate code to reload my table but then after the update the double click on row to open modal, stops to work, you know why and how to fixet?

Comment: @AryWibowo Can we refresh only one row in a table instead of refreshing whole table?

Comment: @Uma, yes It can, (1) you should have unique identifier for your rows, (2) you can change the script to replace your specific row with the new. Just revise the selector and select the row with their row ID. Or you can use reactjs or vuejs, it's easy to make your table always update with your changes

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL, try to look the error on the console log. I think it will give you a hint

Answer (score 3):

use this code

> **$(".table").load(location.href + " .table");**

don't forget to give space before .table Ex: $(".table").load(location.href + "SPACE.table")

Comment: I honestly don't understand why did someone -1 you, this is exactly what i needed according to my code and exact question. +1 from me.

Comment: i think he did not check the code. by the, thank you so much.

Comment: @Hikaros I think it is common thing in Stack Overflow nowadays. They bash -1 Rep to the answer if it is not fulfill his own needs or standard

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="display dataTable no-footer" id="notificationTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="basic-1_info">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th> Title</th>
                    <th> Brief</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>By</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    

                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
```

```js
let notificationTable = $('#notificationTable').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      // 'scrollX': true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ordering": false,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [{
        extend: 'copy',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: '0,1,3,4'
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'CSV',
        className: "csvGenerate",
        action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
          getCSVFile();
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Excel',
        className: "excelMyButtonsToHide",
        action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
          getExcelFile();
        }
      }, {
        extend: 'print',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: '0,1,3,4'
        }
      },
        'colvis'-
      ],
      language: {
        buttons: {
          colvis: '<span class="icon icon-eye" style="font-size: x-small;"/>'
        }
      },
      'columnDefs': [{
        "visible": false,
        "targets": []
      }],
      "ajax": {
        "url": '/system/admin/notifications/allNotifications?fromDate='+ fromStart +'&toDate=' +endDate +'&orderCol=' + ord + '&column=' + col,
        "type": "GET",
        dataFilter: function (data) {
          responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          notificationData = responseData.data;
          return JSON.stringify(responseData);
        }
      },
      "columns": [{
        "data": "id"
      },
      {
        "data": "offerTitle"
      },
      {
        "data": "offerBrief"
      },
      {
        "data": "offerCategory"
      },
      {
        "data": "offerTo"
      },
      {
        "data": "offerBy"
      },
      {
        sortable: false,
        "render": function (data, type, full) {
          let buttonID = "edit_" + full.id;
          return '<a id=' + buttonID + ' class="icofont icofont-edit edit"></a>';
        }
      },
        {
          sortable: false,
          "render": function (data, type, full) {
            let buttonID = "delete_" + full.id;
            return '<a id=' + buttonID + ' class=" icofont icofont-trash trash"></a>';
          }
        },


      ],
    });
$('#notificationTable').on('click', 'a.trash', function (row) {

      let rowId = row.target.id;

      selectedId = rowId.split('_')[1]

      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          axios.delete(`/system/admin/notifications/${selectedId}`).then (function (response){

            $("#addCashback").text("Add").prop('disabled',false)
            if (true){
              //if (response.data.success){
              $("#addNewNotification").modal("hide")
              notificationTable.draw(true)
              notify("Success","Data Saved successfully","success")
            }
            else{
              notify("Error",response.data.errors,"danger")
            }

          })
          Swal.fire(
                  'Deleted!',
                  'Your file has been deleted.',
                  'success'



          ).then(function() {
            notificationTable.draw(true);
          });

        }

      })

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since it only consists of code, could you please explain it a bit above?

Comment: To Refresh a table on you have to add   notificationTable.draw(true);  .It will just refresh table not whole page