# refresh datatable after database update

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

In my html page,I have a table that displays data that come from my database. I want refresh the datatable when my database is updated without refresh all the page. I'm using PHP framwork Laravel.

```html
<table id="example" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr class="headings">
        <th>ID &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>first name </th>
        <th>last name </th>
        <th>E-mail </th>
        <th>birthday </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr class="even pointer">
        <td class=" ">{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{ $user->name2 }}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{ $user->email }}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{ $user->birthday }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use any javascript frameworks such as jQeury/Vuejs to send query to database and display it.

Comment: how can do that, can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function(){
   $( "#mytable" ).load( "your-current-page.html #mytable" );
}, 2000);
<button id="refresh-btn">Refresh Table</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   function RefreshTable() {
       $( "#mytable" ).load( "your-current-page.html #mytable" );
   }

   $("#refresh-btn").on("click", RefreshTable);

   // OR CAN THIS WAY
   //
   // $("#refresh-btn").on("click", function() {
   //    $( "#mytable" ).load( "your-current-page.html #mytable" );
   // });


});
</script>
```

[How to refresh table contents in div using jquery/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254977/how-to-refresh-table-contents-in-div-using-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Use this package, its great and i use it all the time. Which is a laravel wrapper for datatables.net

[Github DataTables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)

Answer (score 0):

Example using jQuery. Note this is but one of 1000 ways to do this. This just outlines the basic idea of the process of building a table using AJAX and Laravel. It's not meant to be a drop-in code segment.

**Basic table code**

```
<table id="example" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th>ID &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>first name </th>
            <th>last name </th>
            <th>E-mail </th>
            <th>birthday </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php // empty for now ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**tablecontents.blade.php**

```
<?php // Requires the $users table ?>
@foreach ($users as $user)
     <tr class="even pointer">
         <td class=" ">{{ $user->id }}</td>
         <td class=" ">{{ $user->name }}</td>
         <td class=" ">{{ $user->name2 }}</td>
         <td class=" ">{{ $user->email }}</td>
         <td class=" ">{{ $user->birthday }}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

**AjaxController.php (or similar)**

```
function getUpdatedTable() {
     $users = //get users
     return view("tablecontents", [ "users", $users ]);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function updateTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/getUpdatedTable",
        success: function (data) {
             $("#example tbody").html(data);
        }

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () { 
     updateTable();
     setInterval(updateTable, 5000); //Re-update every 5 seconds     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned inside the comments, you can use frameworks like `jQuery` to build a real-time module.

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $.get('generic-handler.php')
        .done( function (data) {
            $('#realtime').innerHTML = data;
        });
});
```

Inside your PHP file you put your code to display the database and then you can wrap it in a `setInterval` so your request is sent every `X` number of seconds.

**Documentation:**

[$.get - jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) 
[setInterval - JS](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)