# jQuery AJAX call function on timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to reload my jQuery DataTables without refreshing the page in an attempt to capture new data.

Here is my initial ready function that begins the process:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $.ajax({
     url:'api/qnams_all.php',
     type:"GET",
     dataType:"json"
   }).done(function(response) {
       console.log(response.data);
       renderDataTable(response.data)
   }).fail(function() {
       alert( "error" );
   }).always(function() {
       alert( "complete" );
   });  
 });
```

I'm sending the data to this function:

```
 function renderDataTable(data)
 {
   var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
     "data": data,
     "iDisplayLength": 25,
     "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
     "bDestroy": true,
     "stateSave": true
     // there's some more stuff, but I don't think necessary to show
   });
 }
```

I'm trying to utilize the answer found here: [How to refresh table contents in div using jquery/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254977/how-to-refresh-table-contents-in-div-using-jquery-ajax)

As follows:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
   $( "#example1" ).load( "mywebpage.php #example1" );
 }, 2000);
```

Using all of the above code, when the page first loads, it looks like this:

[image: when the page first loads]

But after the refresh, it looks like this:

[image: after refresh]

The picture immediately above does indeed reload without the page refreshing, but I'm not sure why it looks like the picture above.

Comment: Swapping out the content of the table will blow away the stuff added by DataTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this example will be usefull

```
//Reload the table data every 30 seconds (paging reset)
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json"
} );

setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 30000 );
```

more details -  [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Comment: @HoodCoderMan, I would check this solution first as I think it'll be better.

Comment: If I'm looking at this correctly, am I to add on to var $dataTable = ('#example1').DataTable({ "data": data, "ajax": data.json, ..... });  Is this correct?

Comment: for your example will be something like this: 
var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
 ajax: "api/qnams_all.php"
});

Comment: @D.Dimitrioglo Using the above method, and the text you suggested, I almost got it working.  But now, the problem I have is when the page first loads, all of the records are duplicated.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You should debug your code to find out a reason why are the records duplicated.
There is an `draw` event witch fired once the table has completed a draw.
$('#example1').dataTable();
 
$('#example1').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    console.log('DataTable has drawn!');
});

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to load/render data then call it in document ready and after 2 seconds:

```
function loadAndRender()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url:'api/qnams_all.php',
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"json"
    }).done(function(response)
    {
        console.log(response.data);
        renderDataTable(response.data)
    }).fail(function()
    {
        alert( "error" );
    }).always(function()
    {
        alert( "complete" );
    });  

}

function renderDataTable(data)
{
    var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable(
    {
        "data": data,
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
        "bDestroy": true,
        "stateSave": true
        // there's some more stuff, but I don't think necessary to show
    });
}

$(document).ready(loadAndRender);

setTimeout(loadAndRender, 2000);
```

Comment: Can I use the loadAndRender function to replace the document ready function at the top?

Comment: You define the two functions first. Then you call the `loadAndRender` one twice: first on document ready and then after 2 seconds.

Comment: I would probably check [D.Dimitrioglo's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37469936/3383907) solution first. I don't know anything about `DataTables` but it appears his might be the better way to do it.