# jQuery DataTables duplicates are initially loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, reload

So, adding on to my question from yesterday:  [jQuery AJAX call function on timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469826/jquery-ajax-call-function-on-timeout)

Using the first answer from the post from yesterday, the table does indeed reload without refreshing the whole page.  It does so after 30 seconds.

But my problem lies before the first refresh...

The page loads, and the records are duplicated.  But after the first refresh and every refresh after (unless I manually refresh using F5), everything is fine.  No duplicates.

I'm trying to figure out why there are duplicates and how to remove the duplicates upon the page's initial ready event.

Here is the code, starting with the ready event:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $.ajax({
     url:'api/qnams_all.php',
     type:"GET",
     dataType:"json"
   }).done(function(response) {
     console.log(response.data);
     renderDataTable(response.data)
   }).fail(function() {
     alert( "error" ); 
   }).always(function() {
     alert( "complete" );
   });
 });
```

Here is the function to load the DataTable:

```
 function renderDataTable(data)
 {
   var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
     "ajax": 'api/qnams_all.php',  // just added this
     "data": data,
     "bDestroy": true,
     "stateSave": true
   });

 // then I add the reload function

   setInterval( function () {
     $dataTable.ajax.reload();
   }, 30000 );

 });
```

As stated above, the setInterval function works like how it should.  It's just the initial page load is duplicating all of the records.

Does anyone see why and how to fix it?

Comment: Set a Variable for your data records and on each interval set the variable as "". (blank)

Comment: Pardon, ignore that, use .empty() on the div to clear the data table. Or once its loaded clear the setInterval (unless your checking for new data)

Comment: Would you be able to provide me some sample code of what that would look like?  Please forgive my ignorance regarding this matter.  I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Please use uppercase only for those items which must be uppercase (like HTML). jQuery is spelled with a single uppercase letter, and DataTables only has two. For a lot of people, using all uppercase is analogous to shouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got some duplication going on. You don't need to load the ajax flie and then load it again when you set up the `DataTable`.

Try replacing all of your code with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // load and render the data
  var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
    "ajax": 'api/qnams_all.php', // just added this
    "data": data,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    // the init function is called when the data table has finished loading/drawing
    "init": function() {
      // now that the initial data has loaded we can start the timer to do the refresh
      setInterval(function() {
        $dataTable.ajax.reload();
      }, 30000);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So utilizing your code, I could get rid of the renderDataTable function and just put everything inside the READY event?

Comment: Yes, I thikn so. I don't know anything about `DataTables` but from what I'm reading it should work.

Comment: I will give it a shot.  I will let you know.

Comment: No luck.  Console doesn't recognize "data": data

Comment: I don't think you need `"data": data` since you're using `"ajax": 'api/qnams_all.php'`.

Comment: Success.... @IMTheNachoMan, I did what you said and now the code works.  However, I did have to remove the "init" function.  Then I moved the setInterval function near the bottom of the READY event, and now the table reloads without the page refreshing AND with no duplicates.  Thanks to everyone.  Upvotes to all.

Answer (score 0):

Calling clear prevents duplicate rows while loading data into table:

```
$("#checkResourcesButton").click(function() {
        $.post("./get/resources", {
            featureName: $('#myvar').val()
        }).done(function (data) {
            var table = $('#table-output').DataTable();
            table.clear();
            var json = JSON.parse(data);

            for (var row in json) {
                var nameVal = json[row].Name;
                var emailVal = json[row].emailId;
                var roleVal = json[row].role;
                var startDateVal = json[row].startDate;
                var endDateVal = json[row].endDate;
                var toAdd =
                    {
                        name: String(nameVal),
                        emailId: String(emailVal),
                        role: String(roleVal),
                        startDate: String(startDateVal),
                        endDate: String(endDateVal)
                    };
                table.row.add(toAdd);
            }

            table.draw();
        });
    });
```