# Using a search box in a modal dialog, how do I display the results from the search without reloading the whole page?

Tags: c#, html, search, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

First of all, I have a partial page to create a user and it contains a modal popup to select the user's main contact(which is a person). In that dialog, I have a searchbox so that the person could search the contact with his or her name.

I am able to make the search, but the way I implemented my code is that when I get the results from the search method, I reload the whole page. So when I get the results, it closes the dialog page and I have to reopen it to see the results. How can I simply display the results of the search without having to reload the entire page?

**UPDATE**

I added a boolean property to the main page's model so that whenever the user searches for a contact, when the page reloads, it sets the new property to true and it should force the modal to popup again. It doesn't work as I'm not sure how to force the opening of a modal... any clues?

**This is from the main page**
`

```
@if (Model.SearchedForContact)
            {
                <script>
                    $(function () {
                        $("#find-contact").modal("show");
                    });
                </script>
            }
```

**This is is my modal popup :**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="find-contact">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
            <h3>My Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchUser", "User", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactName)<input type="submit" value="Search" /> // Search button calls the search method from the controller
            }
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Header</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (Model.ContactOptions == null || Model.ContactOptions.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color: red">
                                No Result
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var option in Model.ContactOptions)
                        {
                            //displays the first and last name of each item in the result list
                        }
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is my Search Method from my controller**

```
public ActionResult SearchUser(UserCreationModel model)
    {
        model.ContactOptions = //call to my database to return a list where the name contains the searched name
        return PartialView("_CreateUser", model);
    }
```

I am fairly new to coding, so I realize I might have to use some ajax or jquery perhaps, but I don't know where to start or how to implement it. Please help me!

Thank you.

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254977/how-to-refresh-table-contents-in-div-using-jquery-ajax it explains how to load your table using ajax

Comment: @EdneyHolder Thank you for the link, I updated my post with what I tried to do. I basically added a boolean property to my pages model so that whenever the user searches for a contact, when the page reloads, it sets the new property to true and it should force the modal to popup again. It doesn't work as I'm not sure how to force the opening of a modal... any clues?